# Possible to set the parameters of a bound query in vba before form load?

Tags: ms-access

I've a bound form. The datasource for the form is a query with parameters.
Is it possible to set the parameters in vba before the form loads?
The popup for the parameters pops up even before the form_open event :/

I know of the alternatives .. build my own query strings with parameters, or manipulate the sql of the querydefs. but i dont like them.

at the moment I use unbound forms during designtime and bind them to parameterqueries during runtime. but having unbound forms during designtime is not so handy.

Anyone an idea?

Greetings

Egi

Comment: Can you set the parameters to the values of controls on a hidden form?

Comment: i dont like hidden forms neither ;D.. i like to work with code.

Comment: So .. you do not want to build an sql string, you do not want to change the query def, and you do not want a hidden form. It does not leave a lot of room, does it? I guess you could use ADO, but that will complicate your life even more.

Comment: yeah it doesn't ... as I told you, I m not looking for alternatives but for a way to fill the parameters of a query in vba that is bound to a form during form_open or something. i know that maybe that is not possible, but "myQuery.Parameters("ID").Value = 3" is just so much better then anything else in access, I am really pissed that I can't do it in form_open.

Comment: You will have to look at an alternative - there are many. For example, you could leave the parameters out altogether and apply a filter, or add a Where statement with the parameters to the OpenForm action of DoCmd (4th argument, I think)

Comment: yeah .. docmd.openform(WhereCondition:=bla) is nice as long as you dont try to go with events. because then you can't use DoCmd.OpenForm at all :/ with eventy i had to fake a constructor. so atm i m doing something like this: `private WithEventy myForm as Form_SomeNiceForm set myForm = new Form_SomeNiceForm // fake constructor myForm.Initialize(someID) myForm.Visible = true` and on the other side in the form_open event my initialize procedure checks if an ID is there and builds the appropriate query.

Comment: @Egi Trying to go against the natural behaviour of Access is always going to cause problems, you mention you like to work with code so I'm surprised you like working with vile "bound forms", I'd take the time over an unbound form and go with either building the string or altering the querydef, what is it you dislike about these methods?

Comment: here you got me, i actually dont like to work with access bound forms but i have a program here working that way and it would take too much time to rewrite it. so i though about making the changes i need with minimal impact. rewriting the sql of querydefs is kinda risky in my eyes because if multiple forms are using the same querydef you could run into problems. building the string yourself is ok, i just though that if i already use querydefs with parameters, that there is a way to use them with more flexibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said:

> at the moment I use unbound forms during designtime and bind them to parameterqueries during runtime. **but having unbound forms during designtime is not so handy.**

One alternative would be to use a "dummy" RecordSource so that you have a bound form at design time, but still update the RecordSource using your parameter query at runtime.

An example of a dummy query would be something like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS EmployeeID, 'John' AS FirstName, 'Doe' AS LastName, #1/1/1980# AS DoB
```

That would populate the Field List box with the fields `EmployeeID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DoB`.  Obviously you would want your dummy query field names to reflect what the field names will be at runtime.

This will also avoid the issue of the parameter pop-ups showing at load time.

Comment: I have done this before and it works well. Just change the datasource when then form loads

Comment: mmmh not bad.. maybe someone comes up with another idea. if not i will accept this answer.
my hope is that there is a solution without additional overhead like more querydefs, sqlstrings or other extras. only one form, one querydef and a little vba to cover every condition :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the basic solution here is to simply remove the parameters and NOT change the SQL used. Access forms have a where clause. They are designed to solve this very problem. And this means you don't need a query with parameters and you don't have to modify the form's or report sql.

You simply pass the where clause when you open the form.

So the alternatives of building a query string are NOT required, and the alternative of having to manipulate the sql of a querydef is also not required. And the alternative of having to modify the forms data source is also not required.

And with parameters removed from the query, then you are free to use the query in forms, reports, export routines and all kinds of uses.

Comment: as i mentioned in a comment above, i can't use DoCmd.OpenForm because i m using my own events. i guess custom events are not part of a basic solution then.

Comment: Fair enough. You could simply launch the form and have a custom where property of the form.

myForm.MyWhere = "InvoiceNumber = " & lngIngInvoiceNum

The above would thus set the forms datasource + where clause. And the thus you leave the form's datasource set as a sql with where ID = 0